# App bundling failure using webpack-dev-server command

Tags: angularjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to bundle an angular application using webpack,

This is the `webpack.config.js` :

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
    entry:'./index.js',
    output:{
        path : __dirname + '/app',
        filename:'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

the `app/index.html` looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test ng-webpack egghead</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

when i run `webpack-dev-server` command like shown in the console log :

```
>webpack-dev-server --content-base app
 http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from F:\Learnings\FrontEnd\AngularJs\webpack\egghead.io - AngularJS - Angular and Webpack for Modular Applications\egg-ng-webpack\app
Hash: 98db763b035ecfaba293
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 1089ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  1.22 MB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 1.19 MB [rendered]
    [0] ./app/index.js 120 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] ./~/angular/index.js 48 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] ./~/angular/angular.js 1.19 MB {0} [built]
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

or when i run that same command as an npm script, the log remain the same (it looks as everything is allright) but the `bundle.js` file instead of being generated under the `/app` folder as set in both the `output.path`, it's as generated under the app root(the file isn't written in the disk actually) and it will be available only via the url `http://127.0.0.1:8080/bundle.js` instead 
of `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/bundle.js` as supposed to be (then when trying to load app/index.html in the brower i get the error (`GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/bundle.js 404 (Not Found)`) and after repeating the same process many times, now i'm not getting the bundle file anywhere but the log remains the same as above.

When i replaced the command webpack-dev-server with just webpack inside the `package.json` :

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack --content-base app"
  },
```

now the bundle.js exists under `/app` and it's shown via `http://127.0.0.1:8080/app/bundle.js` and the index.html loads perfectly without errors.

Answer (score 0):

setting the publicPath property in the config file did solve the problem :

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
    entry:'./index.js',
    output:{
        path : path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
        publicPath: "app/",
        filename:'./bundle.js'
    }
};
```